# What triggers the SSRS to generate a log file or modify a current one?

Tags: configuration, ssrs, database-internals, trace, ssrs-2016

When running a trace on my new SSRS Reporting Services 2016, after troubleshooting some problems related to [migrating](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/215083/22336) [from SSRS 2008](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/143812/22336), I find the following pattern running continuously:

[image]

Here is the continuously run script:

```
--========================================================
--the script that is run over and over 
-- by the SSRS service
--========================================================



    declare @BatchID uniqueidentifier

    set @BatchID = NEWID()

    UPDATE [Event] WITH (TABLOCKX)
        SET [BatchID] = @BatchID,
        [ProcessStart] = GETUTCDATE(),
        [ProcessHeartbeat] = GETUTCDATE()
    FROM (

        SELECT TOP 4 [EventID] 
          FROM [Event] WITH (TABLOCKX) 
         WHERE [ProcessStart] is NULL 
      ORDER BY [TimeEntered]

        ) AS t1
    WHERE [Event].[EventID] = t1.[EventID]

    select top 4
        E.[EventID],
        E.[EventType],
        E.[EventData]
    from
        [Event] E WITH (TABLOCKX)
    where
        [BatchID] = @BatchID
    ORDER BY [TimeEntered]


set @BatchID = newid()

UPDATE [Notifications] WITH (TABLOCKX)
SET [BatchID] = @BatchID,
[ProcessStart] = GETUTCDATE(),
[ProcessHeartbeat] = GETUTCDATE()
FROM (

    SELECT TOP 4  [NotificationID] 
        FROM [Notifications] WITH (TABLOCKX) 
        WHERE ProcessStart is NULL and
    (   ProcessAfter is NULL 
        or ProcessAfter < GETUTCDATE()) 

    ORDER BY [NotificationEntered]

) AS t1
WHERE [Notifications].[NotificationID] 
        = t1.[NotificationID]

    select top 4
    -- Notification data
    N.[NotificationID],
    N.[SubscriptionID],
    N.[ActivationID],
    N.[ReportID],
    N.[SnapShotDate],
    N.[DeliveryExtension],
    N.[ExtensionSettings],
    N.[Locale],
    N.[Parameters],
    N.[SubscriptionLastRunTime],
    N.[ProcessStart],
    N.[NotificationEntered],
    N.[Attempt],
    N.[IsDataDriven],
    SUSER_SNAME(Owner.[Sid]),
    Owner.[UserName],
    -- Report Data
    O.[Path],
    N.[ReportZone],
    O.[Type],
    SD.NtSecDescPrimary,
    N.[Version],
    Owner.[AuthType],
    SR.[SubscriptionResult]
from 
    [Notifications] N with (TABLOCKX) 

    inner join [Catalog] O 
            on O.[ItemID] = N.[ReportID]

    inner join [Users] Owner 
            on N.SubscriptionOwnerID = Owner.UserID

    left outer join [SecData] SD 
                    on O.[PolicyID] = SD.[PolicyID] 
                AND SD.AuthType = Owner.AuthType

    left outer join [SubscriptionResults] SR 
                    on N.[SubscriptionID] = SR.[SubscriptionID] 
                AND CHECKSUM(convert(nvarchar(max),N.[ExtensionSettings])) 
                    = SR.[ExtensionSettingsHash]

where 
    N.[BatchID] = @BatchID
ORDER BY [NotificationEntered]
```

In the meantime SSRS generated another log. There is nothing significative in the log, it is all information only, as you can see on the partial view picture below:

[image]

All seems normal. So the question is:

What triggers the SSRS to generate a report - other than an exception or error somewhere?

Where in SSRS can I go to have a look\modify this behaviour if possible?

I have checked [the config files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/backup-and-restore-operations-for-reporting-services?view=sql-server-ver15):
You should backup these alongside the report server databases:

1. Rsreportserver.config
2. Rssvrpolicy.config
3. Rsmgrpolicy.config
4. Reportingservicesservice.exe.config
5. Web.config for the Report Server ASP.NET application
6. Machine.config for ASP.NET

This is the log in question:

[image]

The modified date of the file has just changed and I noticed SSRS added information to this same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log in question I believe is

Report Server Service Trace Log and it turned ON by default

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/report-server-http-log?view=sql-server-ver15

I figured this by checking where the log is stored in the question.

[image]

> Trace log behavior is managed in the configuration file
>   ReportingServicesService.exe.config. The configuration file is found
>   in the following folder path:
>
> \Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS13.\Reporting
>   Services\ReportServer\bin.

if you want to disable this logging you can do the below.

> DefaultTraceSwitch    Specifies the level of information that is reported
>   to the ReportServerService trace log. Each level includes the
>   information reported by all lower-numbered levels. Disabling tracing
>   is not recommended.   Valid values are:
>
> 0= Disables tracing. The ReportServerService log file is enabled by
>   default. To turn it off, set trace level to 0.

You can tweak this value based on your requirements.

```
0= Disables tracing. The ReportServerService log file is enabled by default. 
   To turn it off, set trace level to 0.

1= Exceptions and restarts

2= Exceptions, restarts, warnings

3= Exceptions, restarts, warnings, status messages (default)

4= Verbose mode
```

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/report-server-service-trace-log?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

SSRS creates a row in the dbo.Event table whenever it queues up a report. It appears all that you're observing is SSRS continuously checking to see if anything is queued so that it can be executed.